# Fedex tracking in Magento (Pop Up) not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, fedex

When either I or my customers try to track Fedex shipments within Magento admin or the store, we get an error - http://screencast.com/t/D1jFoMeSxn3

Is anyone else experiencing this? UPS seems to work fine. This is Mage 1.7.02

Cheers!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue or did you purchase the extension mentioned below?

Answer (score 0):

Core magento does not support printing 'official' FedEx shipping labels (with bar code).  Magento 1.6 claims to support many features, but you need to buy an extension for Shipping Labels to be able to track packages "by reference".  (Using a unique reference ID generated by the Magento store):

This is the extension we are using:
   http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-extension.html

It also supports "Event Based Tracking" where emails get automatically sent by FedEx.com,  this is also tied to Label Printing.